# How do you bind a touch function with Zepto properly?

Tags: javascript, zepto

I'm trying to bind an event to the touchstart, touchmove, and touchend properties that will track the location of the touch. Here's my code:

```
$('#container').bind('touchstart touchmove touchend', function (event) { updateFinger(event); });
```

And the update finger function:

```
var updateFinger = function(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  fingerX = e.data.x1;
  fingerY = e.data.y1;
  alert(fingerX + ' ' + fingerY);
}
```

I know the function is called, but from what I can tell, e.data.x1 and e.data.y1 don't exist (As well as .x). I'm using the code in the documentation, can anyone help me out with this?

EDIT: I fixed the problem, it turns out I was using the wrong code.

Instead of

```
e.data.x1
```

You need to use

```
e.touches[0].pageX
```

Comment: That's great. Could you create an answer for that and mark it as accepted. This way, your question will move out of the "unanswered" lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
e.data.x1
```

You need to use

```
e.touches[0].pageX
```